# Ipad microsoft 365 legacy dropdown list not working

Tags: ipad, office365, dropdown

The legacy dropdown list works well in desktop windows Word with some sections that are restricted for editing. However, the dropdown list did not work when I access it using microsoft 365 word in IPad. The options (score 1 to 5) for 10 items could not be selected. The list is not allowed to drop down. The 10 dropdown list is used with field update (tally bookmark)to calculate a weighted score of 10 items.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thank you!

Tried finding the section number and developer tab of Word 365 but to no avail.